# Toggle pausing .sleep in python

Tags: python, sleep, keypress, pause

This is currently what I'm working with as a reminder after I press certain keys

```
import keyboard
import time
import threading
from playsound import playsound

def handle():
    time.sleep(30)
    print("text")
    playsound("file location.wav")

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "f4":
        t = threading.Thread(target=handle)
        t.start()
```

However I'm looking to add an option that can pause the countdown toward the file being played and then resume it when pressed again

I am not very good with python and any help is *very* appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hello and good day to you.

Hope this helps (If you insist on using "threading" package!)

```
import keyboard
import time
import threading
from playsound import playsound

i = 30
stop_threads = True

def countdown():
    global stop_threads
    global i
    while i:
        if not stop_threads:
            print('Sec ' + str(i))
            time.sleep(1)
            i -= 1
        else:
            break
    else:
        print('Alarm!')
        playsound('file.wav')


while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "f4":
        t = threading.Thread(target=countdown)
        t.daemon = True
        stop_threads = False
        t.start()
    if keyboard.read_key() == "f3":
        stop_threads = True
        t.join()
```